# collapse a list of ndarray to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list containing objects of type numpy.ndarray, all list elements has same .shape value.

How can I collapse this into a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you mean this:

```
>>> alist = [np.array([item, item+1]) for item in range(5)]
>>> alist
[array([0, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4]), array([4, 5])]

>>> np.array(alist)
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  5]])
>>>
```

or actually you want a matrix:

```
>>> np.matrix(alist)
matrix([[ 0,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 4,  5]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [`numpy.vstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) or [`numpy.hstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack), depending on whether you want the arrays to become the rows or the columns of the matrix.

From the manual:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> np.vstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```